# Problems for Hail0.2 working on Azure DataBrick

Tags: python-3.7, azure-databricks, genome, hail

Hello? Anyone who can help for Hail 0.2 on Azure DataBrick?

After pip install  lots of problems came out....

can't find Java Package , import hail.plot , hl.init()

According to document

https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/applications/genomics/tertiary/hail.html#create-a-hail-cluster

I've pip install hail

set  ENABLE_HAIL=true       in Cluster Environment Setting

However

```
import hail as hl
hl.init(sc, idempotent=True)

AttributeError: module 'hail' has no attribute 'init'
```

Also another document

https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/applications/genomics/tertiary/hail.html

```
import hail as hl
import hail.expr.aggregators as agg
hl.init(sc, idempotent=True)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hail.expr'
```

Anyone can give a solution?
Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the genomics runtime? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/runtime/genomicsruntime#dbr-genomics to launch a cluster with the genomics runtime. Then Hail will be installed if you set the `ENABLE_HAIL=true` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to move to Azure HDInsight, and follow the instructions on the following page, under the **Microsoft Azure** section:

https://hail.is/docs/0.2/cloud/other_cloud_providers.html

This should get you up and running!